# Why does $\frac{|\sin\theta|}{2}<\frac{|\theta|}{2}<\frac{|\tan\theta|}{2}$ not imply that $1>\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}>1$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I was watching [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-8/v/sinx-over-x-as-x-approaches-0) proof of the equality $$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$$

The author says about the following [areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoFw3.png) that
`red area <= yellow area <= blue area`. Which leads to the following inequality:

$$\frac{|\sin\theta|}{2} \le \frac{|\theta|}{2} \le \frac{|\tan\theta|}{2}$$

and in the end proofs the theorem.

$$1 \ge \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \ge 1 $$

I noticed that the statement `red area < yellow area < blue area` about the [areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoFw3.png) is also true and in fact more accurate. But this would lead to the following:

$$\frac{|\sin\theta|}{2} \lt \frac{|\theta|}{2} \lt \frac{|\tan\theta|}{2}$$

...

$$1 \gt \lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} \gt 1 $$

Obviously that cannot be true.

Have I just broken the proof?

Comment: Consider $a_n=\dfrac1n$ for $n\in\{1,2,...\}$.   $a_n>0$ but $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I mean that any value cannot be greater than 1 and less than 1 at the same time

Comment: The limit of a sequence of strict inequalities is a non-strict inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good first question! Even if $f(x)<M$ for some value $M$ and for every $x\neq x_0$ in the domain of $f$, you still can't conclude that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)<M$. The most you can say is that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq M$. For example, if $f(x)=1-x^2$, then $f(x)<1$ for all $x\neq0$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to0}1-x^2=1$.

In your case, you have:
$$\cos\theta<\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}<1$$
for every $\theta\neq0$ (at least in a neighborhood of $\theta=0$), so in the limit you have:
$$1\leq\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\leq 1$$
which is true! So the proof is not broken after all.

Comment: The proof is not based on the result you quote. Rather it is based on Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh OP's issue does not seem to be with the squeeze theorem, but rather with the apparent contradiction when trying to strengthen the inequalities to be strict and obtaining $1<1$. I am not giving a proof - just showing why the apparent contradiction does not follow from the strict inequality.

Comment: Yes I know that part (at least that's what I could gather from question). Asker also believes that this is about taking limits of inequalities. When dealing with inequalities like $f\leq g$ a key assumption is that limits of $f, g$ exist and then we conclude $\lim f\leq \lim g$. Squeeze Theorem excels here by only assuming limits of $g, h$ and then inequalities $g\leq f\leq h$ and $\lim g=\lim h$  allows you to infer the existence of $\lim f$.

Comment: I later checked the video at khanacademy which is linked in question. The video uses the term Squeeze Theorem but fails to highlight the key part of the theorem. It appears that the explanations in khan academy for calculus are no different that typical ones given in calculus books and like them they gloss over the key aspects.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is based on Squeeze Theorem which can be stated as

> **Squeeze Theorem**: Let $f, g, h$ be real valued functions defined in a certain deleted neighborhood $I$ of $a$ and further let $$g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x) $$ for all $x\in I$. If $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} h(x) =L$$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) $ also exists and equals $L$.

Now here is another obvious fact which holds the key: *if $a, b$ are real numbers such that $a<b$ then $a\leq b$*. Why is this obvious? Because by definition $a\leq b$ if and only if "$a<b$ or $a=b$".

Thus if we have $$g(x) <f(x) <h(x) $$ then it automatically implies $$g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x) $$ and you can apply Squeeze theorem.

Understanding how order relations work is a must to have a grasp of calculus. The statement of Squeeze Theorem has hypotheses which take care of both the strong and weak inequalities and the conclusion holds in both cases.

---

I later checked the video at Khan Academy linked in question which talks about the inequalities involved $$1\geq \frac{\sin\theta} {\theta} \geq \cos\theta\tag{1}$$ and then mentions "Squeeze Theorem" and then draws the conclusion $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}1\geq \lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\geq \lim_{\theta\to 0}\cos\theta\tag{2}$$ Well, Squeeze Theorem is not about equation $(1)$ implying equation $(2)$ but rather it says if $(1)$ holds and we also have $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}1=\lim_{\theta\to 0}\cos\theta\tag{3}$$ (which is true) then the limit $$\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} $$ also exists (that's the big conclusion we seek: the existence of limit) and it equals the limits in $(3)$ (that's the smaller part of the conclusion: value of limit).

If we use strict inequalities like $$1> \frac{\sin\theta} {\theta} > \cos\theta\tag{4}$$ then this is already included in $(1)$ and we have $(3)$ also so that the conclusion holds.

Thinking in this manner one should observe that the real surprise here is $$1>\cos\theta$$ and yet their limits are equal. But then the surprise gets diluted to obviousness because no one seriously has a doubt in $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\cos\theta=1$.